# Select (Checkmark) same checkbox on multipage form using post with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

New to coding and looking to find a way to select the same check-box marked on the first page of my multiple paged form, So for example the user check marks the box named (**Red**) and on submit page 2 will auto fill the box named (**Red**) to continue with the form process.. Im hoping this can be done by Posting the Variable across from page 1 and have maybe some basic php to check and mark the appropriate box on page 2 that was selected from page 1.

Basic example....   -- Page 1 --
Three Options to choose from on page 1

```
[ ]  GREEN
[X]  RED              <---  User has ticked the red box
[ ]  BLUE

[NEXT PAGE SUBMIT BUTTON]
```

--  Page 2 ---  Automatically Shows the box named RED as check-marked from carrying the page 1 post variable across.

```
[X] RED

..Users Name..
..Users Email..
..Users Number..

[  FINAL SUBMIT  ]
```

Any advice and help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: store the value of the checked box in a session

Comment: If you need the values just for the next page, use the post value and check the respective checkbox or if you need it for multiple pages use session instead.

Comment: if i use session, When sent by post how would i check mark the box again, What function would i use? For example if i was to echo it back to the user it would display it in text wouldn't it? Im only just learning php so please excuse my ignorance if im talking nonsense! im just unsure how to check mark the box from the post variable and what function i would use to do so.. Thanks for taking the time to help out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. In your form1.php:

```
<?php

if ( !empty($_POST) )
{
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['checkboxes'] = $_POST['checkbox'];
    header("Location: /page2.php");
}

?>

<form ...submit to form1.php (This page)>
<input name="checkbox[]" value="RED" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="BLUE" />
<input name="checkbox[]" value="GREEN" />
```

page2.php:

```
<?php

session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['checkboxes']);
//Will be something like:
//array(0 => 'RED', 1 => 'GREEN');
```

Take a look [here](http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) for more info on how to do a checkmark page in PHP, and it can give you more information.

If you're attempting to echo out the checkboxes again, preserving which ones are checked, you can do something like this:

```
echo '<input name="checkbox[]" value="RED"' . (@in_array($_SESSION['checkboxes'], 'RED') ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' />';
```

Comment: Hi Frankerz, my inital thoughts was to echo the outcome however after further css and display work on the website it looks cleaner and better to have the correct check box marked automatically depending on user selection. There is 3 boxes available to check mark on page 1, and a submit button, On page2 there is the 3 check boxes plus further form input fields, Im trying to get the page to automatically check mark the correct box so the user can continue to complete the additional fields.  please feel free to visit ( http://www.surveyorlocal.co.uk/ ) as they have something very similar.

Comment: So, post the form with the 3 checkboxes to the next page. Don't even use `$_SESSION`, just follow my solution but use `@in_array($_POST['checkboxes'], 'RED')` instead. You're going to have to do some of this on your own, I've pretty much given you the entire solution.

Comment: No Problem FrankerZ thanks for your help, im currently working on the pages now so i will try to get the code working and get back to you as quick as possible, hopefully accept as top answer :) Thanks for your time to help out.

Comment: @Birdy If you're done, you should accept this answer

Comment: DavidY not had chance to work with it right now but will do as soon as possible, The only reason i have not accepted it is just in case i need some more help fro FrankerZ when working with the code later today. i will accept this now and comment later if there is anything im stuck with and hopefully still be able to seek help :)  Thanks all ...